# Exclude all parent properties when using IncludeMembers

Tags: c#, automapper

```
public sealed class LookupDetails
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public sealed class File
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public sealed class UserFile
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public File File { get; set; }
}

CreateMap<UserFile, LookupDetails>()
   .IncludeMembers(x => x.File);

CreateMap<File, LookupDetails>();
```

I would like to make it work as projection, `UserFile.File.Id => LookupDetails.Id` and `UserFile.File.Name => LookupDetails.Name`, but it takes `Id` from `UserFile.Id`.

I've tried `ForAllMembers(x => x.Ignore())` and `ForAllOtherMembers(x => x.Ignore())` - does not help.

Also, I'm using queryable extensions, so I'm limited to expression-based configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to map that manually? Does this help?

```
CreateMap<UserFile, LookupDetails>()
    .ForMember(lookupDetails => lookupDetails.Id, options => options.MapFrom(userFile => userFile.File.Id))
```

Edit:

This mapping looks curious (and kind of odd). One might want to keep things straightforward and easy to think about. A `LookupDetails` option with an Id that is actually a File Id might not be straightfoward.

If that's an option, try to simplify the model structure. Have each entity have its own Id that is separate from other Ids. For example, `LookupDetails.Id` and `LookupDetails.FileId`

Comment: It mostly defeats the whole idea of using `IncludeMembers` in this case, because I want to reuse existing mapping `File => LookupDetails`. I've updated code section in question.

Comment: I'm not sure, I added a suggestion to reconsider model structure if that's possible

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing `IncludeMembers`. You just need

```
CreateMap<UserFile, LookupDetails>().ConvertUsing((s, _, context) => context.Mapper.Map<LookupDetails>(s.File));
```

Comment: Your answer is not compatible with EF projections/queryable extensions so it is not an option.

Comment: That's an _essential_ part you didn't mention :) Regardless, you're misusing `IncludeMembers`. If `LookupDetails` is a member, you can use `MapFrom`. That would work with `ProjectTo`.

Comment: How exactly `MapFrom` can help? All classes and maps are included in question.

Comment: It helps if you call `classWithUserFile.ProjectTo<ClassWithLookupDetails>()`, then you can have `ForMember(d=>d.LookupDetails, o=>o.MapFrom(s=>s.UserFIle.File))`.

Comment: Its a top level query, `Context.Query<UserFile>().ProjectTo<LookupDetails>()`. There are no classes in my question that have property named `LookupDetails`: `ForMember(d=>d.LookupDetails, o=>o.MapFrom(s=>s.UserFIle.File))`

Comment: Of course there aren't :) I was making a point. What you want goes against AM's design and requires explicit configuration.

Comment: Then it is not an answer, isn't it? My example is a perfectly valid usecase.